# Crashing when array is moderate sized (1000x1000 int) - change stack size?

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks, stack-size

I am trying to use a simple program to draw a Mandelbrot Set - the program produces an array of integers which correspond to colors in an image. I am working in Code::Blocks on Windows with gcc/MiniGW. It works great for small array sizes (~500x500). However, when I try and run after setting to 1000x1000, it crashes ("has stopped responding"). The same code compiles and executes successfully for any array size under a linux remote terminal using gcc (CentOS) with no special calling instructions.

I think what I need to do is increase the stack size under Code::Blocks. To this end I have tried "-Wl,--stack,1024" under linker options in Code::Blocks. However I can no longer build -"unrecognized command line option '--stack,1024". Is there something wrong with this call?

I'll put the code here but since it works on Linux as expected I don't think it is the issue.

```
int cal_pixel(double complex d,double b, int Nmax){
int count = 1;
double complex z = 0;
while (cabs(z) < b && count < Nmax){
    z=cpow(z,2)+d;
    count=count+1;
}
return count;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
unsigned int color[M][N];
int i;
int j;
double complex d;
double dx;
double dy;
double b = 2;
char delim;
delim = ',';
dx = 2*b/(M-1);
dy = 2*b/(N-1);
FILE *fp;
d=-3+0.1*I;
for (j = 0;j < N; j++){
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++){
            d=(i*dx-b)+(j*dy-b)*I;
            color[i][j]=cal_pixel(d,2,250);
        }
}
fp = fopen("color.csv","w+");
for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++){
        fprintf(fp, "%d", color[i][j]);
        fprintf(fp, "%c",delim);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of playing with the stack size, try to make the array `static` or allocate it dynamically using `malloc()`.

Comment: 4 megabytes is not "moderate".  Simply move "color" up two lines to fix your problem.

Comment: `--stack,1024` looks like very strange syntax for a binutils option. Try `--stack=1024`.

Comment: Please format your code correctéy. Is is unreadable.